# Node.js Mongoose "object.newProperty" fails adding new property to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am fetching fields from Mongo using mongoose and trying to assign a new key to returned result. However, when I log the object after assigning the new key, the key is not present in the logged object.

Strangely, if I log obj.newKey, it gets logged as expected, but the seems missing from the object on logging the entire object.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

const V = require('../../../models/KB/V');

router.post('/fetch-v', async (req, res) => {
  const { idSC, idDC, idP, from, to } = req.body.tp;
  const nds = Math.ceil((to - from) / 86400000 + 1);
  // All set. Now query database for visas:
  let vs = await V.find({
    idSC,
    idDC,
    idP
  }).exec();
  vs.map(v => {
    v.nds >= nds ? (v.applicable = true) : (v.applicable = false);
    console.log('v.applicable:', v.applicable); // Refer Log 1
  });
  console.log('vs:', vs); // Refer Log 2
  return res.send({ success: true, vs });
});
```

**Log 1**

```
v.applicable: true
v.applicable: false
```

**Log 2**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "vs": [
      {
          "_id": "5d51acd41255b4499021bffa",
          "idSC": "5d4e9273928a933e44ba8b56",
          "idDC": "5d4e7318c8562b2bf6e4c33f",
          "idP": "5d4e74742e0e3c2d2ab5428e",
          "nds": 89,
          "createdAt": "2019-08-12T18:15:48.329Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-08-12T18:15:48.329Z",
          "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d51acd41255b4499021bffb",
        "idSC": "5d4e9273928a933e44ba8b56",
        "idDC": "5d4e7318c8562b2bf6e4c33f",
        "idP": "5d4e74742e0e3c2d2ab5428e",
        "nds": 2,
        "createdAt": "2019-08-12T18:15:48.329Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-12T18:15:48.329Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Disregarding the fact you're performing database operations based on the body of a POST request (big no-no), is `vs` an object or an array?

Comment: @jmkmay Model.find() returns an array, so vs is an array. Thanks for the additional comment about code quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await V.find({...})` return an array of **mongoose.Document** so if you want to add new property to its elements, you can use [.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean) on it.

Example:

```
let vs = await V.find({...}).lean();
```